# Ресурсы для изучения Powershell

Tags: windows, сервер, powershell

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ресурсы для изучения Windows Powershell v3-5, особенно в плане управления сервером! Нашел пока только [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/changing-computer-state?view=powershell-5.1), но там только основы, есть ли что-то еще?

Comment: На английском есть множество книг. В частности, [здесь ссылки](https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#powershell) на бесплатные.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что поиск книг на сайте является оффтопиком. So - не сайт со списком книг.